# Need a table for a custom object for community user VF page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

I am new to salesforce developement. I am unable to create a table of a custom object records in a community-user accessed visual force page. I can access individual record by using wrapper class. However I cannot display a table and if I use list of wrapper objects in the apex:repeat value, I get this error (as they are not SObjects):

" can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable."

I also need to support inline-editing once this is resolved. Are custom object access limited for customer-community users? Issue is there only if O access thru community portal. Any way of achieving inline-editing table of custom objects?

## VF page

```
<apex:page controller="FHController" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:repeat value="{!fhList}" var="rec">
        Series: <apex:outputField value="{!rec.Series__c}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

## Controller

```
public class FHController {
    public List<Funding_History__c> fhList {get; set;}

    public FHController() {
        String id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        fhList = [SELECT id, Series__c, Date__c, Amount__c, Valuation__c, Investors__c FROM Funding_History__c WHERE Account__c = :id];
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        System.debug('COUNT: ' + fhList.size());
        update fhList;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any wrapper-classes for displaying SObject on VF-page. You need just select set of Funding_History__c objects and don't wrap it. Then you be able to get these objects on VF-page in {!fhList} variable. 
For inline editing you can use **apex:inlineEditSupport**. Here is quote from SF documentation:

> This component provides inline editing support to 
>   and various container components. In order to support inline editing,
>   this component must also be within an  tag.
>
> The  component can only be a descendant of the  following tags: "apex:dataList", "apex:dataTable", "apex:form", "apex:outputField", "apex:pageBlock", "apex:pageBlockSection", "apex:pageBlockTable", "apex:repeat".
>
> See also: the inlineEdit attribute of "apex:detail"

And here is short example how it looks for Contact object (your case is pretty similar, you just need to change page controller and SObject which you process):

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" id="editButton" value="Edit"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.lastname}">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputField>
                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.accountId}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.phone}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

So, you can to investigate further in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `<apex:pageBlockTable>`  ? This will resolve your first issue as well ( not able to display a table ).